# Generate a matrix of different paths from questions?, Permutations?, Combinations?

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I need a little help in the right direction to get my project started.
Let me explain the situation by giving a little example:

For instance i have 3 questions which can be answered by true or false.
I want to get an overview of all the possible answer combinations.
For example:

```
Question 1          Question 2          Question 3  
True                True                True  
True                False               True  
False               True                False
```

And so on...
Does anybody have an idea how i can program a tool preferably in C# that generates a matrix like above with all the possible outcomes?

Thanks a lot for any feedback or ideas you guys might have!
Greetings Tim

Comment: Hint: For N questions,  this is the same a having a binary number with N bits, giving a maximum value of (2^N)-1. You therefore can use an int to count from 0 to (2^N)-1 and look at the bottom N bits. Each 1 bit corresponds to `True` and each 0 bit corresponds to `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally *rewritten from scratch*. Imagine you have `N` questions (3 in the demo):

```
  string[][] questionsAndAnswers = new string[][] { 
    // Two times Two is Four?
    new string[] { "true", "false"},
    // What is the capital of Russia?
    new string[] { "Berlin", "Moscow", "London"},
    // Sqrt(3 * 3 + 4 * 4) = ? 
    new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "5"},
  };
```

first can be answered as `true/false`, second - one of three cities etc. Then you you can enumerate all the possible answers with a simple routine:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Generator(string[][] answers) {
  int[] indexes = new int[answers.Length];

  while (true) {
    yield return string.Join("\t", answers
      .Select((answer, idx) => answer[indexes[idx]]));

    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; ++i) {
      if (indexes[i] < answers[i].Length - 1) {
        indexes[i] += 1;

        break;
      }
      else {
        if (i == indexes.Length - 1)
          yield break;

        indexes[i] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For instance:

```
  string caption = string.Join("\t", Enumerable
    .Range(1, questionsAndAnswers.Length)
    .Select(i => $"Question {i}"));

  // Or loop - foreach - instead of Join
  string body = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Generator(questionsAndAnswers));

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, caption, body);

  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Outcome:

```
Question 1  Question 2  Question 3
true    Berlin  1
false   Berlin  1
true    Moscow  1
false   Moscow  1
true    London  1
false   London  1
true    Berlin  2
false   Berlin  2
true    Moscow  2
false   Moscow  2
true    London  2
false   London  2
true    Berlin  3
false   Berlin  3
true    Moscow  3
false   Moscow  3
true    London  3
false   London  3
true    Berlin  5
false   Berlin  5
true    Moscow  5 // <- The right answer
false   Moscow  5
true    London  5
false   London  5
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!

But i was wondering is there a way to get the same result from a loop?

The problem description is very basic. 
The situation is that i have a questionnaire where some questions can be answered with true or false, some are open questions, and some questions have multiple answers. Is it possible to create something like above matrix but with the other types of questions in mind ?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: @Tim Occhipinti: sure you can turn the `Join` into a loop, see my edit.

Comment: @Tim Occhipinti: if you have *different types* of questions, please, *specify* them, with a help, say a *tailored class* `QuestionKind`.

Comment: @TimOcchipinti By "different types" of questions, do you mean questions that may have answers that are not "true" and "false", for example "What is the capital of Montenegro?"

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko I don't fully understand what you mean with tailored question...? I must be dumb i guess :P and not a very skilled programmer haha.

But with different types of questions i mean for example: Question 1 can be answered with Yes or No, Question 2 can be answered with a persons email address and Question 3 can be a multi-choice question where the person can answer for example: London, Rome or New York.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes indeed! So the matrix can look like:

`Question 1 Question 2  Question 3  
True           Podgorica    False  
False          Rome          True`

Comment: @Tim Occhipinti: I hope I've got understood you right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you really like ugly lambdas, this can do it in one linq statement:

```
var q1 = new string[] { "true", "false" };
var q2 = new string[] { "Berlin", "Moscow", "London" };
var q3 = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "5" };

var combos = q1.Join(q2, _q1 => true, _q2 => true, (q11, q22) => new { q11, q22 }).Join(q3, _q3 => true, _q2 => true, (q11, q33) => new {q11.q11, q11.q22,q33});
combos.Dump();
```

It does 2 linq (cross) joins to combine the lists in to a final list of all possible combinations.

Output:

```
Question1 Question2 Question3    
true Berlin 1 
true Berlin 2 
true Berlin 3 
true Berlin 5 
true Moscow 1 
true Moscow 2 
true Moscow 3 
true Moscow 5 
true London 1 
true London 2 
true London 3 
true London 5 
false Berlin 1 
false Berlin 2 
false Berlin 3 
false Berlin 5 
false Moscow 1 
false Moscow 2 
false Moscow 3 
false Moscow 5 
false London 1 
false London 2 
false London 3 
false London 5
```